# I want when I choose "go only (flight)", that the second calendar be the same date as the first calendar?

Tags: html, calendar

want when I choose "go only (flight)", that the second calendar be the same date as the first calendar
when I chose aller-simple the 2 calendar rest like aller-retour,help pls.

```
                  <form>&emsp;&emsp;
              <div id="aller-r">
                        <input type="radio" id="aller-retour" name="voyage"  value="aller-retour" checked>
                        <label for="aller-retour">Aller-retour</label>&ensp;
                      </div>
                      <div id="aller-s">
<!--only go-->
                        <input type="radio" id="aller-simple" name="voyage" value="aller-simple">
                        <label for="aller-simple">Aller-simple</label><br>
                      </div>
                    
                  </form>
              </div><br><br><be>
<form  >
               
                        <div class="de-a">
                              &ensp;
                              <label >De:</label>
                              <input type="text" id="form" name="form" placeholder="Ville ou Airport" required>&nbsp;
                              <label >A:</label>
                              <input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="Ville ou Airport" required>&nbsp;
                              <label >Depat:</label>
                              <input type="date" id="depart" name="depart" placeholder="Départ" required >&nbsp;
                            
                                  <script>
                                    depart.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
                                  </script>
                              <label >Retour:</label>&nbsp;
                              <input type="date" id="retour" name="retour" placeholder="Retour" required>&nbsp;
                              
                              <label for="class-voy">Class:</label>&nbsp;
                              <input type="text" id="class-voy" name="class-voy" >&nbsp;
                              <label>Adults:</label>&nbsp;
                              <input type="number" id="Adults-nb" value="1" >&nbsp;
                              <label>Childern:</label>&nbsp;
                              <input type="number" id="childern-nb" value="0" >
                              
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your Retour date change when Aller-simple is selected. See below:

```
...

    <input type="date" id="depart" name="depart" placeholder="Départ" onchange="deChange(event);" required >&nbsp;
                                    
    <script>
    function deChange(e){
       if(document.getElementById("aller-simple").checked){
          document.getElementById('retour').value = document.getElementById('depart').value
       }
    }
    depart.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
    </script>

...
```

I would also recommend editing the radio button `onchange` event to accommodate after-the-fact edits:

```
<div id="aller-s">
    <input type="radio" id="aller-simple" name="voyage" value="aller-simple"    onchange="deChange(event)">
    <label for="aller-simple">Aller-simple</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: sadly nothing change